# VB.Net App to check personal Wordpress site for last post

Tags: vb.net, wordpress

I have a personal website that I want to see when the last post was made to it. Is there a way to find the last posted date on my blog?

In my application, I have a notification that I want to fire if we've made a 'News' post on our site so that our users are aware of any issues and I figured the best way would be to see when the last post was made.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WordPress [supports](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) the [metaWeblog API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi), you could use the [XML-RPC.NET](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) library to create a client that comminicates with your blog. You would use the `metaWeblog.getRecentPosts` method to get the most recent posts. You can find an example here.

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2008/08/19/programming-the-metaweblog-api-in-net-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might even be able to automate the login process, and scrape the post titles, comparing the first one to the one that was stored last. If they're different, it would indicate an update has been made.

Here's a method I came up with to automate the login part:
http://stateofidleness.com/2011/01/vbnet-automated-login-wordpress-site/

You could even connect to the mySQL database and query for the last entry date. (probably easier)